# Convert object to datetime, then split into 2 columns for removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, duplicates

I am having difficulty with converting date object into datetime.

My date & time object within the df looks like this:

```
Date
2/28/20 18:00
```

and I am doing this to convert it to datetime format;

```
from datetime import datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M)
```

I thought this worked as when I do dtypes I am getting the Date column in datetime format. This is how the date column became reflected as after running the above:

```
Date
2020-02-28 18:00:00
```

However after converting to datetime, I would like to split the datetime column into 'Date' and 'Time', with the data displayed like this:

```
Date           Time
2020-02-28     18:00
```

I tried to run this:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['Time'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

but am getting 'AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values'

The main goal I want to achieve after splitting the into 2 columns, date and time, is so that I can then remove duplicates and keep only the last timing for each date in the dataframe.

Any advice appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the next `df['Date'].dt`, `df['Date']` has been converted to string. You need to swap the assign sequence.

```py
df['Time'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```